# How to create a SharePoint Search Result Page programmatically?

Tags: web-part, search, search-results

I want to introduce a new Search vertical for which I may have to create a Search Result Page and configure the Search Result webpart to use the pre-configured Search Result source.

How do I create a new Search Result Page? and configure the Search Result webpart to use the pre-configured Search Result source.

Update:
SharePoint version : 2016
Dev tool : Visual studio

Comment: Please improve your question. Which version of SharePoint? What have you tried? What are your options? PowerShell, CSOM, Etc.

Comment: I could do it every thing on the browser however would like to build a package that would create and configure the search result page.

Comment: It is no different from provisioning any other publishing page.